# Need to graph time series of data set that only shows deltas in data

Tags: excel, datetime, graph, dataset

I have the following data set:

```
Datetime               Solution
2017-06-12 00:10:00    0
2017-06-12 00:10:01    1
2017-06-12 00:10:40    0
2017-06-12 00:11:07    1
2017-06-12 00:13:34    0
2017-06-12 00:20:00    1
2017-06-12 00:29:35    2
2017-06-12 00:31:44    1
2017-06-12 00:38:42    2
```

I want to graph a time series plot of the data set where the x-axis is in seconds (so 00:00:00-00:40:00 for example) where each tick is a second.

The solution only updates when it is changed.  So from 00:10:01-00:10:40, the solution value is 1.  From 00:10:40 - 00:11:07 the solution is 0, and so on.

How can I create a graph in excel that does this?  I've run into this problem before but instead of creating a method to solve it, I usually avoid it.

I'm thinking for excel I may need to create a column of all times (seconds) between 00:00:00 and 00:40:00 and write a script to generate a new column when the solution changes.

Maybe there is an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want each tick to be equal to 1 second then you will have over 1700 ticks on your graph between your first point `2017-06-12 00:10:00` and your last point `2017-06-12 00:38:42` but to do this you select your data and insert a scatter plot graph. Double click the entries on the x-axis to open up the formatting panel (Excel 2013) and select the tab that shows a bar graph (last on the right). Here you can select the value of each major tick mark. Set this value equal to 1 second or 1/86400th of a day (0.0000115740740740741 = 1 / (24 {hours} * 60 {minutes} * 60 {seconds})). It won't be pretty but you can use that logic to adjust your graph tickmarks.